# How to filter the below array of object in multiple combination

Tags: javascript

I want to filter my list of object using below input. I want to check filterInput.name array should check below age array each value checking multiple conditon.

My input:

```
const filterInput = {
         name: ['jhone','joe'],
         age: [22,20]
     }
```

My list:

```
const list = [
 {name: "joe",
 age: 22,
 address: "US"},
{
 name: "jhone",
 age: 20,
 address: "Dubai"
},
{
 name: "elon",
 age: 20,
 address: "Dubai"
},
{
 name: "joe",
 age: 20,
 address: "france"
},{
 name: "sathis",
 age: 20,
 address: "Delhi"
}
];
```

My try (not working):

```
const out = list.filter((item,i)=>{
     if(filter.name==item.name&&filter.age==item.age) return true;
});

console.log(out);
```

I want to check the combination of array like below output I want:

```
output list = [
  {
 name: "jhone",
 age: 20,
 address: "Dubai"
   }, <br/>
 {name: "joe",
 age: 22,
 address: "US"}, <br/>
 {
 name: "joe",
 age: 20,
 address: "france"
}, <br/>
];
```

Example filter condition checking:

1. `if('jhone'==item.name && 20 == item.age)`
2. `if('jhone'==item.name && 22==item.age)`
3. `if('joe'==item.name && 20==item.age)`
4. `if('joe'==item.name && 22==item.age)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the entries of the filter object, and iterate the list by looking to the keys and values of the filter.

```js
const
    list = [{ name: "joe", age: 22, address: "US" }, { name: "jhone", age: 20, address: "Dubai" }, { name: "elon", age: 20, address: "Dubai" }, { name: "joe", age: 20, address: "france" }, { name: "sathis", age: 20, address: "Delhi" }],
    filterInput = { name: ['jhone', 'joe'], age: [22, 20] },
    filter = Object.entries(filterInput),
    result = list.filter(o =>
        filter.every(([k, a]) => a.some(v => v === o[k]))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

filter over the list, and check if the name/age is in the filter array using `includes()`

```
const filtered = list.filter(obj => (
  filterInput.name.includes(obj.name) &&
  filterInput.age.includes(obj.age)
))
```

```js
const filterInput = {
 name: ['jhone','joe'],
 age: [22,20]
}

const list = [
 {name: "joe",
 age: 22,
 address: "US"},
{
 name: "jhone",
 age: 20,
 address: "Dubai"
},
{
 name: "elon",
 age: 20,
 address: "Dubai"
},
{
 name: "joe",
 age: 20,
 address: "france"
},{
 name: "sathis",
 age: 20,
 address: "Delhi"
}
];

const filtered = list.filter(obj => (
  filterInput.name.includes(obj.name) &&
  filterInput.age.includes(obj.age)
))

console.log(filtered)
```